# How to determine a file's Unicode character encoding in IOS?

Tags: cocoa-touch, file-io, ios-simulator

In our application I have to open a text file which will be sum time UTF-8 format or UTF-16 format .

Is there any way to determine the file format of a file? Or Is it possible to check the readied 'NSString' is valid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following do-catch blocks as stated in the documentation if you are forced to guess the encoding of your text file, which works for Swift 4.0:

```
do {
    let str = try String(contentsOf: url, usedEncoding: &encodingType)
    print("Used for encoding: \(encodingType)")
} catch {
    do {
        let str = try String(contentsOf: url, encoding: .utf8)
        print("Used for encoding: UTF-8")
    } catch {
        do {
            let str = try String(contentsOf: url, encoding: .isoLatin1)
            print("Used for encoding: Windows Latin 1")
        } catch {
            // Error handling
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apple's documentation has some guidance on how to proceed: [String Programming Guide: Reading data with an unknown encoding](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/readingFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003459-SW4):

> If you are forced to guess the encoding (and note that in the absence of explicit information, it is a guess):
>
> Try stringWithContentsOfFile:usedEncoding:error: or initWithContentsOfFile:usedEncoding:error: (or the URL-based equivalents). These methods try to determine the encoding of the resource, and if successful return by reference the encoding used.
>
> If (1) fails, try to read the resource by specifying UTF-8 as the encoding.
>
> If (2) fails, try an appropriate legacy encoding. "Appropriate" here depends a bit on circumstances; it might be the default C string encoding, it might be ISO or Windows Latin 1, or something else, depending on where your data is coming from.

Comment: Add a comment with link to the answer instead of copy-pasting it as your own. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4940563/1407017

Comment: i am so sorry , i will next time