# Guess NSData encoding using file in /tmp as intermediation?

Tags: macos, cocoa, encoding, nsstring, nsdata

I want to guess a received NSData's encoding. I searched in Stackoverflow and found one [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351151/guess-encoding-when-creating-an-nsstring-from-nsdata) which indicates "can't".

However, I noticed a NSString method `stringWithContentsOfFile:usedEncoding:error:`, and I wanted to know whether I can achieve this goal in sequence below:
**1>** Get an NSData object
**2>** Store this NSData object into a file with random file name in directory */tmp*
**3>** Call `NSString`'s `stringWithContentsOfFile:usedEncoding:error:` method to read from this temporary file.
**4>** Delete the temporary file.
**5>** Read the `enc` parameter to determine the encoding

I know I can experiment by myself, but I have no various data source with different encoding in my hand. Therefore I raised a question here. Could my opinion work? Could this solution find every possible encoding OS X could recognized?

Comment: Don't guess about encodings ;)

Comment: Why? I have an application to fetch target device's wireless network IDs and display them. But those IDs may in various encoding which may cause display errors... :(

Comment: What I meant is: SSIDs

Comment: Yeah, it's a really tough problem to solve :( your solution could work, but even if the string is not `nil` (meaning that the framework was able to "guess"), the guess could be totally wrong and end up showing your user total nonsense. You should try your solution and enter a lot of strange SSID in different encodings and see how they work.

Comment: Thanks! I will try every encoding I could guess and create. I may make _display_ as first thing to do, even displaying wrong. At least this make the application work.